# Why is typescript converting this nullish coallesce to a ternary?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular app and I have the following code:

```
    // ...
    this.x = y ?? z;
    // ...
```

When I run `ng serve` I get the following error in my terminal:

```
error TS1109: Expression expected.
error TS1005: ':' expected.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (47:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         // ...
|         this.x = y ?  ? z :  : ;
|         // ...
```

Why is it converting the nullish coallesce (`y ?? z`) to a ternary (`y ?  ? z :  :` )?

I have tried adding brackets around the nullish coallesce but it doesn't change the output.

Comment: looks bug to me...

Comment: Which version of angular are you targetting ? do you have a `browserslist` config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you are using a TypeScript version that supports the nullish coalescing operator. The nullish coalescing operator was introduced in TypeScript 3.7.